# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined with websockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new with NodeJs. why am I getting this error please **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined ?**
I try to realise a chat with websockets. Help me please ! thanks

```
var html = require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname + '/simpleChat.html');
var server = require('http').createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.end(html);
});
server.listen(8080);
var nowjs = require('now');
var everyone = nowjs.initialize(server);
everyone.now.distributeMessage = function (message) {
  everyone.now.receiveMessage(this.now.name, message);
};
```

Comment: var html = require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname+'/simpleChat.html');
var server = require('http').createServer(function(req, res){
  res.end(html);
});
server.listen(8080);

var nowjs = require("now");
var everyone = nowjs.initialize(server);

everyone.now.distributeMessage = function(message){
  everyone.now.receiveMessage(this.now.name, message);
};

Comment: Please [edit] your post.